# How can I fill in the blanks to display just my image?

Tags: html, css, jsf

```
<h:inputText id="email"
    value="#{user.user.email}"
    title="Email"
    onchange="this.form.submit()"
    required="true" requiredMessage="_____">
<f:validator validatorId="checkvalidemail"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="email" styleClass="error"/>
```

validation:

```
String enteredEmail = (String)object;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(enteredEmail);
boolean matchFound = m.matches();    

if (!matchFound) {
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
message.setSummary("____");
throw new ValidatorException(message);
```

and css

```
.error {
background-image: url('includes/style/delete2.png');
text-align: left;
font-size: 36px;
}
```

Thank you very much
Best Regards
Ignacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:message>` renders a HTML `<span>` whose dimensions depends on the node value. If there's nothing, then it will simply collapse and you won't see the CSS `background-image`. You need to make it a [block](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) level element with a fixed size instead.

```
.error {
    display: block;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background-image: url('includes/style/delete2.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Add if necessary `float: left;` if you want to keep it on the same line.

Comment: As usual you are right! Thank you very much Balus it worked!!